# Is $(a+b)^*$ closed under reversal?

Tags: formal-languages

If you have a language $L_1 = \{ w | w \in \{a,b\}^* \}$. Then does the language $L_1^R$ (the reversal of $L_1$) have the exact same elements as the language $L_1$?

My Logic: Since $L_1$ can contain a string as well as the reversal of the string (ex. $L_1 = \{ababba, abbaba\}$), then $L_1^R$, over the same alphabet, can contain the same strings as what $L_1$ has (ex. $L_1^R = \{abbaba, ababba\}$ which is equivalent to $L_1$)?

Am I looking at this correctly?

Comment: I think you must be misusing the '=' sign or something, because you seem to be defining $L_1$ in two contradictory ways.

Answer (score 1):

If an arbitrary language $L$ is closed under reversal ($L=L^R$), then $L^*$ is also closed under reversal, since

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
  L^R &= \{ w_1 \ldots w_n \ |\ \forall i.\ w_i \in L \}^R \\
      &= \{ (w_1 \ldots w_n)^R \ |\ \forall i.\ w_i \in L \} \\
      &= \{ w_n^R \ldots w_1^R \ |\ \forall i.\ w_i \in L \} \\
      &= \{ x_1 \ldots x_n \ |\ \forall i.\ x_i^R \in L \} \\
      &= \{ x_1 \ldots x_n \ |\ \forall i.\ x_i \in L^R \} \\
      &= \{ x_1 \ldots x_n \ |\ \forall i.\ x_i \in L \} \\
\end{array}
$$

So, being $\{a,b\}$ trivially closed under reversal (provided $a,b$ are letters, not words), $\{a,b\}^*$ is such.

Answer (score 0):

Going back to saying $L_1 = \Sigma^*$ is valid, as $\Sigma^*$ is trivially closed under reversal.

If you're unsure, and the language is more complicated, you can do more legwork to make verify your claim: Create the minimal DFA for the language $L$, and create the minimal DFA for $REVERSE(L)$. It isn't the most efficient way, but it simplifies comparison. (It also allows to find a counter-example if the language isn't closed under reversal).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You are looking it the correct way. $L$ will contain all the string possible over alphabet $a$ and $b$ so $\forall w \in L$ there exist $  w^R \in L$